# W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7d358f1010 disconnect failed

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

```
package com.example.yj.bluetoothapplication;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.UUID;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "bluetooth2";

Button btnLed1, btnLed2, btnLed3, btnpado;
TextView txtArduino;
RelativeLayout rlayout;
Handler h;

final int RECIEVE_MESSAGE = 1;        // Status  for Handler
private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
private static int flag = 0;

private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

// SPP UUID service
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

// MAC-address of Bluetooth module (you must edit this line)
private static String address = "98:D3:61:FD:59:9D";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnLed1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLed1);
    btnLed2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLed2);
    btnLed3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLed3);
    btnpado = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPado);

    txtArduino = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtArduino);
    rlayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    h = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case RECIEVE_MESSAGE:
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                    sb.append(strIncom);
                    int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n");
                    if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {
                        String sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);
                        sb.delete(0, sb.length());
                        txtArduino.setText("Data from Arduino: " + sbprint);
                        if(flag%4==3){
                            rlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
                        }
                        else if(flag%4==1){
                            rlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
                        }
                        else if(flag%4==2){
                            rlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 255, 0));
                        }
                        else if(flag%4==0){
                            rlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 255));
                        }
                        flag++;
                        btnLed1.setEnabled(true);
                        btnLed2.setEnabled(true);
                        btnLed3.setEnabled(true);
                        btnpado.setEnabled(true);

                    }
                    break;
            }
        };
    };

    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();       // get Bluetooth adapter
    checkBTState();

    btnLed1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mConnectedThread.write("1");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn on First LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    btnLed2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mConnectedThread.write("2");
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn on Second LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    btnLed3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mConnectedThread.write("3");
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn on Third LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    btnpado.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mConnectedThread.write("0");
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turn on all LEDs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10){
        try {
            final Method  m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", new Class[] { UUID.class });
            return (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, MY_UUID);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not create Insecure RFComm Connection",e);
        }
    }
    return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Log.d(TAG, "...onResume - try connect...");

    // Set up a pointer to the remote node using it's address.
    BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

    // Two things are needed to make a connection:
    //   A MAC address, which we got above.
    //   A Service ID or UUID.  In this case we are using the
    //     UUID for SPP.

    try {
        btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
    }

    // Discovery is resource intensive.  Make sure it isn't going on
    // when you attempt to connect and pass your message.
    btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    // Establish the connection.  This will block until it connects.
    Log.d(TAG, "...Connecting...");
    try {
        btSocket.connect();
        Log.d(TAG, "....Connection ok...");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage() + ".");
        }
    }

    // Create a data stream so we can talk to server.
    Log.d(TAG, "...Create Socket...");

    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
    mConnectedThread.start();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    Log.d(TAG, "...In onPause()...");

    try     {
        btSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to close socket." + e2.getMessage() + ".");
    }
}

private void checkBTState() {
    // Check for Bluetooth support and then check to make sure it is turned on
    // Emulator doesn't support Bluetooth and will return null
    if(btAdapter==null) {
        errorExit("Fatal Error", "Bluetooth not support");
    } else {
        if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "...Bluetooth ON...");
        } else {
            //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
        }
    }
}

private void errorExit(String title, String message){
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), title + " - " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();
}

private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);        // Get number of bytes and message in "buffer"
                h.obtainMessage(RECIEVE_MESSAGE, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();     // Send to message queue Handler
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(String message) {
        Log.d(TAG, "...Data to send: " + message + "...");
        byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "...Error data send: " + e.getMessage() + "...");
        }
    }
}
```

> D/BluetoothSocket: close() this: android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket@d1bd8ab, channel: 1, mSocketIS: android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream@218b08, mSocketOS: android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketOutputStream@6d4d2a1mSocket: android.net.LocalSocket@a50ecc6 impl:android.net.LocalSocketImpl@3bd5487 fd:java.io.FileDescriptor@ec84fb4, mSocketState: CONNECTED D/ViewRootImpl@3a2e96b[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1 D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@a62bffa[MainActivity] getNavigationBarColor() -855310 D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=76 W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7d358f2010 disconnect failed D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0x7d1f6ac180, 0x7d358f2000 D/ViewRootImpl@3a2e96b[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,2280] new=[0,0][1080,2280] result=0x5 surface={valid=false 0} changed=true D/ViewRootImpl@3a2e96b[MainActivity]: setWindowStopped(true) old=false D/ViewRootImpl@3a2e96b[MainActivity]: Surface release. android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.setStoppedState:669 android.app.Activity.performStop:7647 android.app.ActivityThread.callActivityOnStop:4378 android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner:4356 android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity:4431 android.app.servertransaction.StopActivityItem.execute:41 android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState:145 android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute:70 D/BluetoothSocket: close() this: android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket@f21e178, channel: 1, mSocketIS: android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream@eefc051, mSocketOS: android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketOutputStream@853c0b6mSocket: null, mSocketState: CLOSED Process 30538 terminated.

---

Comment: Please, add more details to your code.

Comment: Improved formatting of error message.